# CInt and GetHashCode

Tags: c#, vb.net

I came across some weird VB codes, when I am about to convert some VB codes to C#:

```
totalLinks = table1.Rows(i).Item("qty").GetHashCode) *  CInt(table2.Rows(i).Item("numOfLinks").GetHashCode + 1)
```

(The business logic should be getting the total of links = qty * numOfLinks).

table1 is a Datatable, and qty & numOfLinks are two columns from it.

Question1: Can we get a Integer by applying 'CInt' to a hashcode like above?

Question2: What does it mean by letting hashcode plus 1 and then get converted to integer like above? (should be converted to integer first and then plus 1? or I actually misunderstood the codes?)

I don't know how to convert it to C# before I understand exactly the meaning. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone had no idea what they were doing with this code, but just got lucky that it worked.

GetHashCode happens to return the underlying value for Integer variables because there is really nothing to hash.

Therefore, you can (should) simply ignore the GetHashCode code and convert the code as

```
totalLinks = CInt(table1.Rows(i).Item("qty")) * (CInt(table2.Rows(i).Item("numOfLinks")) + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense now!

Comment: I see the MSDN that the GetHashCode will convert hash code for an object, could you please advise why there is nothing to hash? The column is not an object?

Comment: The database column type is almost certainly an integer (you can check the type on the Column), so when the value is retrieved from the DB it is stored as a System.Int32, which is actually not an object and which is why the code always worked. If it was an actual object (string, for example), then you would have had some very strange and incorrect multiplication values.

Comment: Yes, it's an int. Thanks for the explanation!